# remove keys with empty values from json using JS

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
{
  "top": [{
    "language": "English",
    "value": ""
  }, {
    "language": "German",
    "value": "hASTA"
  }],
  "bottom": [{
    "language": "English",
    "value": "jfgfjg"
  }, {
    "language": "German",
    "value": "fkjhf"
  }],
  "In": "12 am",
  "Out": "3 am",
  "Type": ""
}
```

Hi guys, I want to remove the keys that have empty values, I tried using `filter` but that showed me error in google sheets.
I want to send only the data to API that has values.

In this case, for

> language:german, the value is empty so i Would skip sending **top**. to the API.

the json to be sent:

```js
{
  "bottom": [{
    "language": "English",
    "value": "jfgfjg"
  }, {
    "language": "German",
    "value": "fkjhf"
  }],
  "In": "12 am",
  "Out": "3 am"
}
```

code used:

```
apidata = userdata.filter(function(x) { return x !== "" });
```

Can you please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Can you supply the code you tried? i.e. how you tried to use `.filter()`

Comment: Why is the entire `top` array removed from the object?

Comment: @adiga, API is configured to accept the request only if both the languages are present.

Comment: @Sean I have added the code that I used,

Comment: @MisterJojo I am doing this in google apps script in google sheets. so

Comment: @MisterJojo The context of the environment in which the code is running gives valuable information. For eg, until recently, Google apps script only supported ES5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

userdata.filter won't filter the keys of the object.

---

You can use Array.reduce to create your new object

```js
const json = {
  "top": [{
    "language": "English",
    "value": ""
  }, {
    "language": "German",
    "value": "hASTA"
  }],
  "bottom": [{
    "language": "English",
    "value": "jfgfjg"
  }, {
    "language": "German",
    "value": "fkjhf"
  }],
  "In": "12 am",
  "Out": "3 am",
  "Type": ""
};

// returns true if it contains a falsy value
// this function is recursive
function checkFalsy(ptr) {
   // If we are dealing with an array
  if (ptr instanceof Array) {
    return ptr.some(x => checkFalsy(x));
  }
  
  // If we have a string
  if (typeof ptr === 'string') {
     return ptr.length === 0;
  }
  
  // If we have an object
  if (Object.keys(ptr).length) {
     return Object.keys(ptr).some(y => checkFalsy(ptr[y]));
  }
  
  // anything else
  return !!ptr;
}

const filteredJson = Object.keys(json).reduce((tmp, x) => {
  // If we are dealing with an array
  if (checkFalsy(json[x]) === false) {
    tmp[x] = json[x];
  }

  return tmp;
}, {});

console.log(filteredJson);
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did with the `const` in your answer or in a chat room? I've never seen something like that, good solution.

Comment: The `const { }` purpose is to declare new variables from destructuring the `json` variable. The purpose here is to extract the keys `top` and `Type` from the `json` object and put all others keys inside of `filteredJson`. The `top: _` syntax is here to rename the variable where we put the `top` value because `top` seems to be a reserved variable name

Comment: This is giving errors in google apps script. May be this is not supported there. Any can be done with any other method?

Comment: I've edited my post with a new way to do it using `Array.reduce`

Comment: The elements to remove are not known ahead of time, so providing an array of keys to remove won't do anything to meet the need.

Comment: Yes, @Alan Wells is right. I won't know which is empty.It can be different every time

Comment: @AlanWells Please help me out with thjis

Comment: @AlanWells Sorry I misread the question ! I've edited my answer now to remove every empty values .

Comment: @colen in your question you have removed `"top"` key from the object, but it's value is not empty. What is the rule that will make `"top"` to be removed from the original object ?

Comment: The code needs to delete the parent element if one of the child elements has a falsy value.

Comment: @AlanWells I've edited my code accordingly with a function checking recursively for falsy values in children